# Having issues in refresh the activity in android programmatically

Tags: android, android-activity, page-refresh

I have two `Buttons` in my `Activity`. When I click on each button, I have to refresh the page and call one method. That method helps to show some data fetch from `database`.

When I click the first `button`, I am able to get the correct output but suddenly the page gets refreshed. I need to show the output until another `button` is clicked.

please help me. Thanks in advance

CODE:

```
case R.id.button1:
    View view = null;
    refresh(view);
    set_day="Monday";//Monday  
    viewgroups_ineditgroup(set_day);s        
    break; 
case R.id.button2:
    View view1 = null;
    refresh(view1);
    set_day="Tuesday"; 
    viewgroups_ineditgroup(set_day);
    break; 

public void refresh(View view){        
    onRestart();    
}

@Override
protected void onRestart() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onRestart();
    Intent i = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, CurrentActivity);
    i.putExtra("group_name", intentData); 
    startActivity(i);
    finish();
}
```

Comment: I think the reason the page is refreshing is because you are calling onRestart, that is causing the current activity to end and start a new activity, inside the refresh function. I don't see a need for that.

Comment: thnk u 13hsoj. See i need to pass some extra intent to this activity. Thats y i used like this. Please help me

Comment: there is `onNewIntent` that should help you with that problem

Comment: Please paste the code before and after the switch case for buttons

Comment: thnk u. Which code i need to post 13hsoj

Answer (score 0):

the question is if you really need to refresh the activity? the page by itself can be changed without that. You can run changes to the UI thread like this

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        //TODO add ui code here
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void refresh(View view) {
    /*
    1. open the db here
    2. fetch the data
    3. assign the data to your views
    4. close the db
    */
}
```

I don't know why you are passing null as parameter..

Comment: you can perform those 4 steps in runOnUiThread() method as petrumo suggested

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent1 = getIntent();
overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
finish();
overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
startActivity(intent1);
```